# How to upload image file using Multipart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to upload my profile Image file with cookie to my server. But I don't know how to upload it.

Here is my code:

```
  _submit() async {
    Api.updateUserProfileImage(
      context,
      _image,
      await Provider.of<AccountState>(context, listen: false)
          .storage
          .read(key: "cookie"),
    );
  }
```

```
  static void updateUserProfileImage(
      BuildContext context, File image, String cookie) async {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest(
                    "POST",
                    Uri.parse(
                      "YourAPILINK",
                    ),
                  );
                  Map<String, String> headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'token': token
                  };
                  request.headers['token'] = token;
                  request.headers["Content-Type"]='multipart/form-data';
                  request.fields["name"] = "hardik";

                  request.fields["email"] = "h@gmail.com";
                  request.fields["mobile"] = "00000000";
                  request.fields["address"] = "afa";
                  request.fields["city"] = "fsf";

                  if (image != null) {
                    print(image.path.split(".").last);
                    request.files.add(
                      http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                        "avatar",
                        image.readAsBytesSync(),
                        filename: "test.${image.path.split(".").last}",
                        contentType: MediaType(
                            "image", "${image.path.split(".").last}"),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  request.fields["reminder_interval"] = "1";

                  request.send().then((onValue) {
                    print(onValue.statusCode);

                    print(onValue.headers);
                    print(onValue.contentLength);
                  });
```

Comment: what if one of the fields is integer or a list or even a Map?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) contains with an example:

> A multipart/form-data request.
>
> Such a request has both string [fields](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest/fields.html), which function as normal
>   form fields, and (potentially streamed) binary [files](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest/files.html).
>
> This request automatically sets the Content-Type header to
>   multipart/form-data. This value will override any value set by the
>   user.
>
> ```
> var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com/create');
> var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri) // your uri / url (encoded)
>   ..fields['user'] = 'nweiz@google.com' // your fields key - value
>   ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
>       'package', 'build/package.tar.gz',
>       contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar'))); // your file(s)
> var response = await request.send();
> if (response.statusCode == 200) print('Uploaded!'); // what should be done when success
> ```

Note that there is a pacakge powerful Http client for Dart/Flutter
called [dio](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio) which support File download and FormData.

Here is its documentation example:

> Sending FormData:
>
> ```
> FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
>     "name": "wendux",
>     "age": 25,
>     "file": new UploadFileInfo(new File("yourfile.extension"), "filename.extension") // if you a file is type of file then no need to create File()
>   });
> response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
> ```